# How can I input a slider/knob in a curved custompaint

Tags: flutter

I just need to know how can I implement knob/slider inside a custompaint bar

I tried what I can, still I cant find the solution to this

My custom bar looks like a mountainlike shape in the middle and valley like in the left and right